# CakePHP Two routes at the same url

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to create two routes at the same url?

So for example:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
```

The idea is that e.g. `www.mywebsite.com` will show the login page as its home page without any redirects to a login page or anything. Once the user logs in then they will be taken to the home page again but instead it will load the home controller index but again same URL!

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you definitely can't do that like that.

You could try setting `/` to `home/index` and checking whether the user is logged in in the `home/index` view, and display the login form if he's not. And also check for user being logged in in the controller.

That said, I really can't image why you would want to do it like that. Especially if you're using the `AuthComponent`.

Comment: Yes I'm using the AuthComponent but what other options would I have if using that except redirect the user to the login action (which isn't what I want to do)

Comment: Well, do what I wrote above. In the `index` method of the `home` controller check for the presence of `$this->data` and use this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1261/login.